# Starting a VB.NET application with specific RAM/heap allocation

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am building an application in .NET 3.5 through Visual Studio 2010 (2013 as well) and a certain process keeps running out of memory. This is actually expected due to the intense data loads.

As my first solution, I would like send an argument to the .NET framework to allow for maximum RAM/heap usage. Similar to the Java argument `XmX4G`.

What is the equivalent argument for a .NET program to expand memory allotment?

Comment: AFAIK, .Net will dynamically grow the heap to use the maximum allowed by the OS.  Are you using large List(of T) where T is a value type?  If so, the internal reallocation after a certain point may be causing the problem.  It doubles its backing each time the internal limit is hit, so pre-allocating the maximum expected items can prevent an out of memory error.

Comment: There is no equivalent switch. Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit process? If it is 32-bit the easiest way to work around OOM issues is to change it to a 64-bit process. If you need to keep it 32-bit, you can make the process large address aware. That'll give you 3 GB on 32-bit Windows and 4 GB on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, how do I accomplish your suggestions in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Set target platform to 64-bit. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328(v=vs.100).aspx